# Reducing to a system of first order DEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to figure out how to reduce this DE into a system of first order differential equations (all derivatives are with respect to $x$)

$$
x^2 y'' + x y' + \left(x^2 - \frac{1}{4}\right) y = 0
$$

So far, all the examples available didn't help me enough to solve this because they weren't easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Its a pretty standard process.

Your equation is x^2y''+ xy'+ (x^2- 0.25)y= 0.

Let u= y' so that y''= u'.  We can write that equation as 
x^2u'+ xu+ (x^2- 0.25)y= 0, the other equation being y'= u.

Comment: The examples I saw used x and y with subscripts.